# Как объединить срезы для индексирования?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Как сделать правильно, чтобы можно было отобразить первые 6 столбцов и один добавленный столбец?

Пробовал сложить 2 среза, но выдает полностью все столбцы с `NaN` вместо значений:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False
df = pd.read_excel(r'R:\TEST.xlsx')
df['НОВЫЙ СТОЛБЕЦ'] = ''
df = df.loc[2:]
print df.iloc[:,1:7]
```

Comment: У вас второй питон? И Pandas тоже какой-нибудь древний?

Comment: @CrazyElf 2.7.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [np.r_[...]](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) для конкатенации срезов:

```
iumport numpy as np
```

Пример DataFrame:

```
In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 8)))

In [17]: df['НОВЫЙ СТОЛБЕЦ'] = ''

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 НОВЫЙ СТОЛБЕЦ
0  6  4  6  8  4  3  1  8
1  7  6  2  1  8  5  1  2
2  6  4  7  4  8  9  5  9
```

решение:

```
res = df.iloc[:, np.r_[:6, df.columns.get_loc("НОВЫЙ СТОЛБЕЦ")]]
```

результат:

```
In [20]: res
Out[20]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5 НОВЫЙ СТОЛБЕЦ
0  6  4  6  8  4  3
1  7  6  2  1  8  5
2  6  4  7  4  8  9
```